# How do I delete all rows from all tables in a database from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a database in my mysql.  Inside are tables with each name an email address.  Each table has the same structure.  So something like

```
data (database)
    x@x.com (table name)
        [column 1] [column 2] ... (column names)
```

I'd like to create an event that removes entries after 24 hours.  Unfortunately I'm unable to do something like

```
DELETE FROM data.* WHERE created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

It looks like I'm unable to use the wildcard.  What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Edit:

Truncating all tables is not the proper solution I'm looking for as I'm not looking to purge all data in a table, but rather select data based on a condition.

I found the easiest solution would be to just write a script like Nick mentioned to select the data I need from information_schema and delete the entries I need from each table based on the condition I need.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use dynamic table names in the first place.

Comment: You need to write a procedure that gets all the table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, and constructs dynamic SQL to execute.

Comment: or create an event per table at the same time you create the table.