# How to select latest table date table in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a database test
in that db every day table created with date like **DATAM_D_YYYY**

i want to take every day latest table backup 
i use below command to take back-up
mysql version is 5.7.24

```
mysql -u root -p --xml -e "select * from  test%m_%d_%y" > path.xml
```

but getting rror

Please let me know

Comment: Like [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069098/how-do-i-delete-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-a-database-from-mysql), "This is why you shouldn't use dynamic table names in the first place."

Comment: btw 5.7.1 is a beta release version of MySQL. It should be run in production.

Comment: for 5.7.24 version

Comment: I can tell you a way around, You can create a separate table, where you can store this table name and current timestamp, when you'll create a new table add an entry to this table. And when you want to take a backup, select a record from the new table based on time desc. and take a backup.